# When does Stack Overflow reset the daily login?

Tags: feature-request, consecutive-days

So there's a gold badge called Fanatic, and you need to visit the site for 100 consecutive days to earn it, but what time zone does Stack Overflow use to count the days?

And is there any possible way to change it? Oh, and to prevent spammers, could it be a feature where you can only change in once?